# Looking for something to reflect ultraviolet light at extremely low wavelengths

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, reflection, wavelength

I am looking for some sort of mirror that will reflect ultraviolet light at extremely small wavelengths (200-250 nm). The main purpose of it is to amplify the ultraviolet light and cause it to spread. I am looking for something extremely cheap that would be able to reflect these wavelengths of light at around at least a 50-75% reflection rate. I have looked at high reflectivity mirrors but they are extremely pricey and I was wondering if there were any cheap alternatives I could use.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! I wonder if your question might find better answers at [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Amplify and cause it to spread? Unclear what you are trying to do, could you clarify?

Comment: What I mean is just reflect it. We have a single source of UV light and we are trying to spread it and we are doing this by reflecting it off multiple sources. I am looking for something that can reflect our light.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a shopping request which is generally considered as *off-topic* on most every SE site.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminium has a high reflectivity down to 200nm.

[image: Reflectance]

([image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_coating))

I used to make UV reflecting mirrors by evaporating aluminium onto a glass substrate, which produces optical quality aluminium mirrors. If you don't need this high quality you could simply polish a sheet of aluminium or just use aluminium foil.